# Multiple CSS media queries not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I am including two css files in the html each with media screen queries both for `max-width: 480px`, but the first css files loads and the 480px media query works on my mobile screen but the second css file with the 480px media query does not work for the form that it contains css formatting for. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px)
```

EDIT:
First CSS file with media query

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
nav{
  height: 200px;
}

.main-pic{
  display: none;
}

.desc{
  max-width: 100%;
}
}
```

Second CSS file with media query

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
form, fieldset, #num_content{
    width: 100%;
}

fieldset div{
    width: 100%;
}

.options{
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post more of the actual code? The media query in itself is fine (otherwise it wouldn't work for the first one either), but if we see the entire code, we might spot the issue.

Comment: why don't you combine both in one file, with one media query?

Comment: one css file has the general format for the website and the other css file contains the format for the specific content of each page

Comment: it doesn't matter if you are including both of the files. you can add the code to one media query.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem lay within the browser in the BlackBerry Z10. For some reason, it wasn't reading the `@media screen` in the second css file but everything worked on my Samsung mobile phone.

Comment: I was just stuck for a while and then it occured to me that the problem might be in the browser itself. Life is tough when the different browsers behave differently.